# jQuery getting element relative position

Tags: jquery, position

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="selectable1">
<span class="drag">Some Text</span>
<span class="drag">Some Text</span>
<span class="drag">Some Text and <span class="drag">Some Other Text</span></span>
</div>
```

I need to create a function that will get the relative position of any span (nested or not) to the main parent - #selectable1.

I have tried to use position() but my code does not work:

```
$(".drag").live('click',function(){ 
var relativepos = $('.drag').position().left
alert(relativepos); 
});
```

Any tips?
Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the event, you refer to the current element as `this`, and not by the generic classname. Remember, the class `.drag` refers to many elements while `this` refers to the current element.

```
$(".drag").live('click',function(){ 
  alert( $(this).position().left ); 
});
```

Comment: Thanx but unfortunately I can not get the position relative to my #selectable1 div. I get position relative to document body.

Comment: Set `#selectable1 { position:relative }`.

Comment: Isn't possible to make the nested span to get also the relative position regarding #selectable1?


- it seems that in your demo it works but I am having problems with my code